# JWT Token authentication - Doing it right way

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, cookies, jwt

**Overview of my project structure:**

I have 2 Projects.

1. Asp.net core Web Api
2. Asp.net core Web MVC

---

### **In Web Api Project**

- I am NOT using Asp.net core Identity for login, instead, I am using my own login mechanism.
- `LoginAction` method will authenticate user in database and generate JWT Token.
- I was able to generate JWT Token and Life is smooth till this point.

**Generate Token**

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("requesttoken")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> RequestToken([FromBody] TokenRequest request)
        {        
            var result = await IsValidUser(request);
            if(result)
            {
                var claims = new[]
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, request.Email)
                };

                var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_myAppSettings.SecurityKey));
                var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

                var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    issuer: _myAppSettings.WebsiteName.ToLower(),
                    audience: _myAppSettings.WebsiteName.ToLower(),
                    claims: claims,
                    notBefore: Utilities.GetEST_DateTimeNow(),
                    expires: Utilities.GetEST_DateTimeNow().AddMinutes(5),                    
                    signingCredentials: creds);

                return Ok(new
                {
                    token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token)
                });
            }
            else
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }
        }
```

**Inside Startup class**

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<MyAppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("MyAppSettings"));

            #region Validate JWT Token
            ConfigureJwtAuthService(services, Configuration);
            #endregion

            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

**JWT Validation part (As partial startup class)**

```
public void ConfigureJwtAuthService(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var symmetricKeyAsBase64 = configuration["MyAppSettings:SecurityKey"];
            var keyByteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(symmetricKeyAsBase64);
            var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(keyByteArray);

            var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                // The signing key must match!
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,

                // Validate the JWT Issuer (iss) claim
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = Configuration["MyAppSettings:WebsiteName"].ToLower(),

                // Validate the JWT Audience (aud) claim
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = Configuration["MyAppSettings:WebsiteName"].ToLower(),

                // Validate the token expiry
                ValidateLifetime = true,

                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            };

            services.AddAuthentication(
            options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(o => o.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters);
        }
```

**Sample response of LoginAction Method.**
`{
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkrDtGhuIETDs8OoIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.469tBeJmYLERjlKi9u6gylb-2NsjHLC_6kZNdtoOGsA"
}`

---

### **In Web MVC Project**

- I am consuming above Web Api and passing login parameters and was able to get JWT Token response.
- I am storing JWT Token response in cookie [Manually - `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(key, jwtTokenValue, option);`]
- Based on JWT Token response receive, I am trying to extract claims from that JWT Token, so that I can able to create valid identity of user and login user on the web.

I am trying to achieve something like below:

```
            {
                var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, model.Email)
                };
                var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "login");
                ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);
                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
```

---

### Questions

1. Am I doing right by storing JWT Token in cookie.  Is my manual approach of storing cookie is correct or is there any better way?
2. How can I get claims from JWT in Web Project, so that I can able to singin user using cookie?

Want to do it right way, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Following helped me:  http://blogs.quovantis.com/json-web-token-jwt-with-web-api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following seems to helped me:  http://blogs.quovantis.com/json-web-token-jwt-with-web-api/  not sure whether that is right way of doing or not.

```
/// Using the same key used for signing token, user payload is generated back
        public JwtSecurityToken GenerateUserClaimFromJWT(string authToken)
        {

            var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidAudiences = new string[]
                      {
                    "http://www.example.com",
                      },

                ValidIssuers = new string[]
                  {
                      "self",
                  },
                IssuerSigningKey = signingKey
            };
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            SecurityToken validatedToken;

            try {

              tokenHandler.ValidateToken(authToken,tokenValidationParameters, out validatedToken);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;

            }

            return validatedToken as JwtSecurityToken;

        }
```