# How to generate Jwt token in Asp.net 6.0 web Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I want how to generate jwt token

---

### This is my Controller

```
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        private readonly JwtContext _context;

        public LoginController(JwtContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
       
        [Route("api/Register")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Register register)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(register);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            Console.WriteLine(register);
            var ttt = _context.Registers.ToList();
            return Ok(new { result = ttt });

        }
   
    }
```

This is my Login model where i use to stored information of login

```
 public class Login
    {
        public int LoginId { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my Register model where i use to stored information of Register

```
 public class Register
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
  
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JWT Token authentication - Doing it right way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50651734/jwt-token-authentication-doing-it-right-way)

Comment: i want in .net 6

Comment: logic will be same for even .net6 . take a look at [this](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2021/12/14/net-6-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a demo , you can refer to it.

In Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<IUsersDb>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("IUsersDb")));    
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
   c.SwaggerDoc("V1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Version = "V1",
        Title = "Educal API",
        Description = "Main API Documantation of Educal API"
    });
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Description = @"Please provide authorization token to access restricted features.",
        Name = "Authorization",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
        Scheme = "Bearer",
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
    });

    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id = "Bearer"
                }

                
            },
            new List<string>()
        }
    });
});
// ADD JWT Authentication
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(o =>
{
    o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    o.Events = new JwtBearerEvents();
   o.Events.OnTokenValidated = context =>
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
    o.Events.OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
   o.Events.OnChallenge = context =>
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
    o.Events.OnMessageReceived = context =>
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
    var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JWT:Key"]);
    o.SaveToken = true;
    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JWT:Issuer"],
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
        //ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["JWT:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key)
    };
});
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(auth =>
{
    auth.AddPolicy("Bearer", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
});
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();       
    app.UseSwaggerUI(options => {
        options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/V1/swagger.json", "Main API Documantation of Educal API");
    });
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

IAuthenticationService:

```
 public interface IAuthenticationService
    {
        Models.AuthenticationToken? Authenticate(User user);
    }
```

AuthenticationService:

```
public class AuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly IUsersDb _usersDb;

        public AuthenticationService(IConfiguration configuration, IUsersDb usersDb)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            _usersDb = usersDb;
        }

        public Models.AuthenticationToken? Authenticate(User user)
        {
            var foundUser = _usersDb.User
                   .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == user.Name && x.Password == user.Password);                
            if (foundUser == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            //If user found then generate JWT
            return CreateAuthenticationToken(foundUser);
        }

        private Models.AuthenticationToken CreateAuthenticationToken(User user)
        {
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var tokenKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["JWT:Key"]);

            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                {
                new(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Name),
                }),

                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(tokenKey),
                    SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };

            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

            return new Models.AuthenticationToken()
            {
                Token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token),
            };
        }
    }
```

AuthenticationToken:

```
public class AuthenticationToken
    {
        public string Token { get; set; }
    }
```

UsersController:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UsersController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IAuthenticationService _authenticationService;
        private readonly IUsersDb _usersDb;

        public UsersController(IAuthenticationService authenticationService, IUsersDb usersDb)
        {
            _authenticationService = authenticationService;
            _usersDb = usersDb;
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("authenticate")]
        public IActionResult Authenticate(User user)
        {
            var token = _authenticationService.Authenticate(user);

            if (token == null)
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }

            return Ok(token);
        }
}
```

User

```
public class User
    { 
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }  
        public string Password { get; set; }    
    }
```

IUsersDb:

```
public class IUsersDb : DbContext
    {
        public IUsersDb(DbContextOptions<IUsersDb> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
    }
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "IUsersDb": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=IUsersDb-7dc5b790-765f-4381-988c-5167405bb107;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "JWT": {
    "Key": "fc746b61cde4f6665d3f9791446cd5395661860c0075a905ed9810b7391af467",
    "Issuer": "Comply",
    "Audience": "comply"
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: `AuthenticationService` is it controller

Comment: @gourav  AuthenticationService is a class.

Comment: in my case i also have register class then how i create token in register  class or login

Comment: In your case, you can get user in your login  model. Then pass the user to AuthenticationService.

Comment: @gourav You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72781617/asp-net-core-identity-use-different-user-table) to get the user from the login model, then generate the token.